# Getting a compiler error when not waiting for a promise?

Tags: typescript, async-await

Currently TypeScript allows me to do something like this:

```
async function getSomething():Promise<Something> {
    // ...
}
```

Then later:

```
const myObject = getSomething();
```

Then later when I try to use `myObject` it gives strange errors.

What I'm wondering is - is there any way to make TypeScript display an error when I get promise without `await`? I couldn't find any flag for this but maybe I missed it.

Comment: How do you use myobject?

Comment: [TypeScript 3.6 improved the error messages for Promises](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-6/#improved-ux-around-promises)

Comment: In this example your `myObject` is a `Promise<Something>` that might not have been resolved yet, even without explicitly stating the return type in your function. So accessing it might cause the issues you mentioned there depending on what you are referring to. @Lucas linked you the blog post wherein TS itself will warn you about this. Otherwise you can always use a linter with appropriate rules for this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply type your object:

```js
const myObject: Something = getSomething();  // error, it returns Promise<Something>

const myObject: Something = await getSomething();  // works, it returns Something
```

Comment: I usually rely on type inference to make the code simpler. Adding the type to everything would mean dropping type inference, which I'd rather avoid.

Comment: but here it's the confusion on different type inferences that lured you, so it this "simpler code" is not helping you.

Comment: @Pac0, the problem is that using type inference is an "all or nothing" thing. Either it works and can be used everywhere, or it has some limtations, as in this case, and shouldn't be used at all. In my case, I guess I'll continue to use it everywhere anyway, and just pay more attention to promises.

Comment: @laurent This issue is not only for TS / JS. As a C# developer, I also encounter the issue (with "Task" instead of "Promise"). However, in my C# IDE there are warnings if you write an `async` function that doesn't contains any `await`. Maybe a more acceptable solution for you would be some TSLint rule that mimics this, which I unfortunately can't look for right now.